What is the relation between broadband connection (PPPoE) and ethernet?
I once dialed up on my router so I did not need to create a broadband connection on my PC.
Now, I dial up on my PC so I need to create a broadband connection on my PC. There are two active networks on my PC: One is the broadband connection (PPPoE) and the other is the Ethernet. I wonder the relation between them.
Does the traffic go through the broadband connection first, then through the ethernet, then go to the router?
The following is the route table on the PC:
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2   4260
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link   202.212.101.132     36
  202.212.101.132  255.255.255.255         On-link   202.212.101.132    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.2   4516
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2   4516
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2   4516
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2   4516
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   202.212.101.132     36
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2   4516
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   202.212.101.132    291
===========================================================================

The IP address 192.168.1.2 is assigned to the ethernet and 202.212.101.132 is assigned to the broadband connection.
I only see the traffic goes to the broadband connection (line 2) but I cannot figure out the role of the ethernet here.
But I think the ethernet does play a role because it corresponds to the physical network adapter which I connect to the router.

pppoe is a bidirectional bytestream over ethernet. That is needed because telecommunication companies have a trouble to understand the packet-oriented communication, so they invented pppoe where they still could remain on their good old byte stream ways, and let you pay for serving internet.

Can you add a diagram of your network, including your PC and any modems or routers? There's something weird in your setup.

I think this answer needs some background context to clear some things up, because your Question uses networking terms in a very unusual way that makes it hard to parse out what you may be asking.
Back before broadband, we got online through dial-up modems over plain old telephone service landlines. The protocol we used to send Internet traffic over those dial-up modems was called PPP. Dial-up ISPs created network infrastructure based on PPP, so their infrastructure routers would expect to receive lots of customer PPP connections forwarded from their pool of modems that received the customers' dial-up calls.
At the same time, in offices and some nerds' homes, people were building "local area networks" (LANs) with Ethernet cables and Ethernet hubs/switches. Ethernet LANs allowed for people to share printers and do multiplayer LAN gaming and share files with other LAN users via file servers, and access and database servers and other corporate IT infrastructure.
When broadband technologies like DSL came along, it replaced "dialing up". Unlike a dial-up modem, a DSL modem is a device that's always connected to the Internet via DSL, and just translates between DSL and Ethernet, connecting your whole Ethernet LAN to the Internet full time, without needing to make a PPP connection. But the problem for many ISPs at the time was that their infrastructure was still based on PPP. So some ISPs, instead of fully modernizing, decided to keep PPP involved. So PPP-over-Ethernet (PPPoE) was created so those ISPs that wanted to keep their PPP-based infrastructure could do so, even though their DSL customers weren't actually dialing up any more; they were using Ethernet to connect to a DSL modem.
Because PPP was still associated with dial-up modems in consumers' minds, some PPPoE client apps were called "broadband dialers" even though there's no dialing going on in broadband. A PPPoE connection is a lot like a VPN tunnel, but without encryption. In fact, many VPN protocols use PPP on the inside of the encrypted tunnel.
So it sounds like you're running a PPPoE client that calls itself a "Broadband Connection". It looks like your PPPoE client has successfully made a connection to your ISP's PPPoE "Access Concentrator" (that's the name for the ISP's big PPPoE server/router that handles the incoming PPPoE connections), which suggests you are on the same Ethernet LAN as a DSL modem. The only mystery to me is why you also have a router on your Ethernet LAN apparently doing NAT and DHCP. Usually the device doing NAT and DHCP has to be the device doing PPPoE. It makes me wonder if you have your DSL modem connected to a LAN port of the router.

There seems no DSL modem. ISP puts an optical modem(Optical Network Unit?) in my home. I use an Ethernet cable to connect my PC's network card to one of the optical modem's Ethernet ports. The optical modem connects to ISP through an optical fiber. The optical modem have two working modes. In one mode, it dials up itself when powering. In the other mode, it won't dial up automatically and I need to dial up on my PC using the created broadband connection. I don't know what you called PPPoE packets are those between my PC and the optical modem, or those between the modem and the ISP.

PPPoE packets go between whichever device is acting as a PPPoE client (this is what you are referring to as "dialing up"), and the ISP. I'm a bit surprised that your ONT is still doing NAT and DHCP if it's also bridging your PPPoE packets. It's not unheard of, but it's not common for a home networking device to simultaneously act as both a NAT gateway and a bridge between LAN and WAN.

I think ISP sets my optical modem work in bridging mode instead of routing mode. So, in this bridging mode, the traffic goes from browser to the PPPoE connection(the adapter/device shown in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" and "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center" ), then the   PPPoE connection device encodes the traffic into PPP packets and sends it to the optical modem in Ethernet physical layer protocol, and then the optical modem sends the packets up to ISP still in PPP packets(but in other physical layer protocol)?

@William Yes, that's correct.

The ONT is probably doing DHCP on its "LAN" connection, so that a connected computer can browse to "192.168.1.1" and configure the device (e.g. to choose between router and bridge mode). When the ONT is in bridge mode, it still does this DHCP, but it does not make a PPPoE connection on its own, does not have a connection to the Internet, and therefore does not do any NAT. The "192.168.1.2" address acquired by the computer is not involved in getting to the Internet.

@twisteroidambassador That's plausible but it would be disappointing if they did it that way when that's exactly what IETF ZeroConf (including link-local addressing) is for.

@Spiff I have seen this type of setup with many ONTs that support both bridge and router mode, so it's at least somewhat prevalent. As for ZeroConf, 1. it does not give a "memorable" address, and 2. browsers don't support browsing to IPv6 link local addresses

@twisteroidambassador ZeroConf doesn't require memorable addresses because services are advertised as human-readable names. But you're right that web browsers not supporting discovering local HTTP[S] services via ZeroConf (DNS-SD) is a problem. Safari used to do it once upon a time, but they implemented it poorly and then removed the feature instead of fixing it. It's not really about the address family per se, it's about web browsers not supporting ZeroConf.

What is the relation between broadband connection (PPPoE) and ethernet?
Your PC uses PPPoE to establish a tunnel which allows to carry IP-related information before you PC has a routeable IP address. IPCP (Internet Protocol Control Protocol) could be carried through that tunnel to assign you PC an IP address. IPCP is one of many control protocols stacked on PPP.
Does the traffic go through the broadband connection first, then through the ethernet, then go to the router?
Downstream, the traffic goes via whatever access network the ISP uses, then through the router (I guess you mean the device installed by the ISP), and then through Ethernet between the router and your PC. PPP is used to tunnel all the way from your PC into the ISP's network.

There are two active networks(Broadband Connection and Ethernet) in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center, the two connections are also shown in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections. I mean how traffic goes through the two devices?

@William: One of them is virtual – it loops back to the OS which takes the "received" packets and sends them out through the real one. (Again, very much like the virtual network adapters installed by VPN apps.)

@u1686_grawity When the traffic goes out of the virtual one, how does the route table route it to the real one? I cannot figure it out in the route table.

@William: It doesn't use the route table, since PPPoE is a tunnel directly over raw Ethernet (it doesn't involve IP at all). The PPPoE client software directly tells the OS what Ethernet frames to send and over which interface.

↑This. @William: PPP is a L2 protocol. IP is a L3 protocol.

@u1686_grawity So, the traffic goes from browser to the PPPoE connection(the adapter/device shown in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" and "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center", i.e., the PPPoE client software?), then the  PPPoE connection sends the traffic directly to the physical network card. No traffic goes from the PPPoE connection to the Ethernet adapter((the adapter/device shown in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" and "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center")?

@William: Well, not quite; the Ethernet adapter/device is the physical network card. Even if the network interface is not used to send IP specifically, it still remains the primary way programs send anything through the card (just using slightly different programming interfaces, e.g. "raw sockets").

@u1686_grawity I see. So the Ethernet adapter/device shown in the control panel exposes two programming interfaces, e.g., "raw sockets" and "ip packets". If a client(in this case, the PPPoE connection, sends the traffic through the Ethernet adapter using the "raw sockets" interface, the route table does not play a role. If a client sends the traffic using the "ip packets" interface, the route table will take part in and find the proper Ethernet adapter to send traffic to? I wonder when a client such as the browser sends traffic, does the route table take part in finding the  PPPoE connection?
